# "bloc init" not found

Tags: solidity, blockchain, nodejs, blockapps

I am trying to start programming with solidity for Ethereum. 
I am working with this tutorial: https://medium.com/@ConsenSys/solidity-integration-with-visual-studio-8bdab2ff8a74#.hunrp4l0i

Apparently I need "Bloc". npm install blockapps-bloc works and gets me a copy of bloc. But I am doing something wrong with "bloc init". What I am supposed to do with that? Just typing it in cmd in the same directory that I have just used to download bloc doesn't work. The Command bloc cannot be found.

What do I have to do to make it work?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to just type the command int the prompt. Try `npm install -g blockapps-bloc`. If that doesn't work, the issue is with your npm configuration

Comment: Wonderful! That actually worked. Thanks :-)! Out of curiosity: What does the -g parameter mean?

Comment: It means "global". When you leave off the flag, it installs it only to the current directory, which is generally not on your path. When you put the `-g` flag, it installs globally, so that the command can be used from anywhere on your computer. In your case, with this kind of command-line tool, that is generally what you want.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why Tjaden Hess chose to comment on this question as opposed to answer it? Why do people do that? Just learning.

Answer (score 1):

After installing with `npm install -g blockapps-bloc`, `cd` into the directory and try
 `bloc.exe init <app-name>`.

When in doubt, check out some documentation: http://developers.blockapps.net/dashboard/quick-starts/visual-studio

This is also similar to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8516/cannot-start-bloc) StackExchange question.

Comment: The link is broken.